# How to convert 4 ints (range 0..255) to uint32_t

Tags: c++

I have 4 ints, `int r = 255`, `g = 255`, `b = 255` and `a = 255`. I would like to convert them to `uint32_t`.

```
uint32_t c = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

in a manner

```
uint32_t c = 0x(int)r(int)g(int)b(int)a;
```

Does this require byte operations?

Comment: `Does this require byte operations?` Bit operations? Yes, it does. Is that the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We might be able to answer your question more sharply if you posted a *brief* code to show what you had tried.

Comment: `#define U(x, y) ((static_cast<uint32_t>(x & 0xFF) << y)` and `uint32_t c = U(r, 24) | U(g, 16) | U(b, 8) | U(a, 0);` followed by `#undef U`.

Comment: @Eljay Would it not be preferable to avoid preprocessing macros in C++?

Comment: True.  An inline function or possibly a lambda could be used instead, to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple different ways:

```
unsigned long c =
    ((static_cast<unsigned long>(r) & 0xFF) << 24) |
    ((static_cast<unsigned long>(g) & 0xFF) << 16) |
    ((static_cast<unsigned long>(b) & 0xFF) <<  8) |
    ((static_cast<unsigned long>(a) & 0xFF) <<  0);

unsigned long d;
unsigned char *pd = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&d);

// only works on little-endian CPUs

*pd++ = static_cast<unsigned char>(a);
*pd++ = static_cast<unsigned char>(b);
*pd++ = static_cast<unsigned char>(g);
*pd++ = static_cast<unsigned char>(r);
```